# How to make change to an array object that is declared in another file

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning to build a website that can be customized based on the value that is entered but the user. I have a question - I am declaring an object array into a different js file so I can access it to different HTML files and I am able to import that file that hs the object array defined. But I cannot make that changes to that object meaning if I import that file to an HTML file where I am taking input from the user, and I am aking changes to it (adding the value that was entered by the user), then the changes are only being saved if I access that object within the same file but I need to make the change globally (meaning when I am printing the object to the other HTML files other then the file where I am making the change to the object, it is just printing me out an empty object). So can anyone please help me with how to do it?

Here is the sample of the file.

`

```
var dataObject = [{ companyName: " ",
 color: " ",
 employee: " ",
 supervisor: " ",
 customer: " " }]`
```

Here is the HTML file where I am making changes and then if I access `dataObject`, then it is printing with the values that I need.

```
function getValue(){
 var condition = false;
 var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
 var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
 var employee = document.getElementById("employee").value;
 var supervisor = document.getElementById("supervisor").value;
 var customers = document.getElementById("customers").value;
 for(let i = 0; i < dataObject.length; i++){
  if(dataObject[i].companyName == " "){
    dataObject[i].companyName = name;}}
```

After aking the changes over I can print the change that I made but I cannot access the changes from the files other than this.
Here ist eh example of it

```
<script src = "customizer.js"></script>
<script>
   console.log(dataObject[0].companyName)</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should store your changes. Web pages don't know about changes in other pages. There are two ways to tackle that: You can create a single page, or you can store your changes in a database, and access that from the sites.

Comment: The middle script is on a single page that is form. But the changes that I made to form are not being saved into the object